# Label and comment make a web address. An Easter egg in Netbeans?

Tags: java, eclipse, netbeans, web, editor

It is well known, that if we'll put a web address as a line in a `Java` method, it should and would be interpreted as a label with // comment after it.

```
public static void setUpClass() throws Exception {
      https://www.google.cz/  <------------------------------- This one 
      FailOnThreadViolationRepaintManager.install();
}
```

It seems, that `NetBeans` has one more interpretation for that: It really interprets the whole line as a web address. It works as web address! When mouse-hovering over it with pressed `Ctrl` you see the name of the site, and if you click, the page appears in the default browser.

[image]

Is it a bug? A feature? Or an Easter egg?

**Edit.**

Eclipse works almost the same way. But it shows the line as a link *only* with pressed CTRL + hovering. Whereas Netbeans shows it as a link *constantly*.

Comment: Looks like a bug in NetBeans...

Comment: follow me into the http://www.ihateeclipse.com/ club ^^. Considering this, I would say it is neither a bug nor a feature, just normal behavior...

Comment: Actually eclipse does do this, if you have ctrl held in.

Comment: I'd say it's a bug, because there's no way that compiles, right?

Comment: @EmbattledSwag It does compile, since it's just a label and a comment.

Comment: @KevinWorkman The jar file won't use the web link, I am afraid, so I can't say it is compiled in all its beauty...

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that. How would a jar file use a label in the code?

Comment: @KevinWorkman You have said that the feature IS compiled. But the feature is the http link in the code.

Comment: Right, but it's just a label. This doesn't result in a compilation error at all. IDEs (both netbeans AND eclipse) seem to recognize urls anywhere in the code, including this corner case. I don't think it's a bug, just an arcane feature.

Comment: @KevinWorkman I think thus, too. But it is a funny enough feature.